# Bitwise operation for MCP4922

Tags: stm32, spi

I want to use the MCP4922 with my STM32F411RE microcontroller. I am working on the data that will be sent over SPI. A write command to the MCP4922 consists of 16 bits. First 4 bits for the configuration and the last 12 are data bits.

```
uint8_t data[2];
```

This is the decleration of the data variables
I put a 1 in the SHDN configuration of the MCP4922 -> 0001 0000 = data[1](https://github.com/murjay/MCP4922-DAC-Driver/blob/master/MCP4922_DAC_driver.c).
At the end I want to generate a sine wave, so I implemented a sine table like this:

```
    uint16_t sine_wave[] =
{
0x800,0x900,0x9fd,0xaf1,0xbda,0xcb3,0xd79,0xe29,
0xec0,0xf3c,0xf9b,0xfdb,0xffb,0xffb,0xfdb,0xf9b,
0xf3c,0xec0,0xe29,0xd79,0xcb3,0xbda,0xaf1,0x9fd,
0x900,0x800,0x6ff,0x602,0x50e,0x425,0x34c,0x286,
0x1d6,0x13f,0xc3,0x64,0x24,0x4,0x4,0x24,
0x64,0xc3,0x13f,0x1d6,0x286,0x34c,0x425,0x50e,
0x602,0x6ff,0x800
};
```

Now I want to put my sine table values in the data bits of data[1](https://github.com/murjay/MCP4922-DAC-Driver/blob/master/MCP4922_DAC_driver.c) and data[0].

```
    void MCP4922_SendByte(uint16_t dac_data)
{

  data[1] |= (0x01 << 4);   
  data[1] |= ((dac_data >> 8) & 0x0f);

  data[0] |= dac_data;  

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, SPI1_LDAC_Pin,1);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, SPI1_CS_Pin, 0);

  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, SPI1_CS_Pin, 1);

  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, SPI1_LDAC_Pin);

}
```

But the values I have on my SPI line are not as expected.

For example the first value 0x800, I want to send 0x1800
-> 0001 1000 0000 0000

The transmit function is initialized as 16 Bit so data[1](https://github.com/murjay/MCP4922-DAC-Driver/blob/master/MCP4922_DAC_driver.c) and data[0] getting transferred. Somehow my bitwise operations are not working but I don't know why. I found exactly this way here. https://github.com/murjay/MCP4922-DAC-Driver/blob/master/MCP4922_DAC_driver.c

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
data[1] = ((dac_data >> 8) & 0x0f) | 0x10;
data[0] = dac_data;
```

Simplify the math, and remove `|` bitwise OR operation from the places where it must not be (otherwise you will use the values already existing in those locations.

Comment: In this way the configuration bits are hardcoded and i cant change them in the future. later on i want to call the function with a specific configuration

Comment: But it worked! thanks